# Why typescript complains about redux slices' initialState type in reduxToolkit createSlice function, even though it is correct type?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

My createSlice() function:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type TransferDeckModeType = "pipetting" | "evaluation" | "editing";

var initialState: TransferDeckModeType = "pipetting";

const transfer_deck_mode = createSlice({
  name: "transfer_deck_mode",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setTransferDeckMode(state, action: PayloadAction<TransferDeckModeType>) {
      let newState = action.payload;
      return newState;
    },
  },
});

export const { setTransferDeckMode } = transfer_deck_mode.actions;

export default transfer_deck_mode.reducer;
```

I get a typescript error on `setTransferDeckMode`.

```
Type '(state: "pipetting", action: { payload: TransferDeckModeType; type: string; }) => TransferDeckModeType' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<"pipetting", { payload: any; type: string; }> | CaseReducerWithPrepare<"pipetting", PayloadAction<any, string, any, any>>'.
  Type '(state: "pipetting", action: { payload: TransferDeckModeType; type: string; }) => TransferDeckModeType' is not assignable to type 'CaseReducer<"pipetting", { payload: any; type: string; }>'.
    Type 'TransferDeckModeType' is not assignable to type 'void | "pipetting"'.
      Type '"evaluation"' is not assignable to type 'void | "pipetting"'.ts(2322)
(method) setTransferDeckMode(state: "pipetting", action: PayloadAction<TransferDeckModeType>): TransferDeckModeType
```

Where is the 'void' coming from? What is setting the type to 'void | "pipetting"'. I don't see where my state could possibly be void.

I feel like I'm missing where to declare the state of the slice, but for some reason I am blind. I thought it could be inferred from the type of initialState.

If I change the initialState type to `string` the error goes away.

```
var initialState: string = "pipetting";
```

But that doesn't make sense - why can't I declare the type of the initialState?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the reason why the RTK docs show

```
var initialState = "pipetting" as TransferDeckModeType ;
```

instead.

TypeScript does flow analysis here. You can experiment with that in [this TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZzgWwKZQBYzAcwB4AVAPgAo8ZYBDAGwGUoaoMAuRYgSkQG9EATlhACk-KrUbNWiAL5yAUFACeABwyIAavRAZkiALyIA5DWOIAPiYBGxhQt4KAbjQGIJMekxbstOvYYmZgDcCgD0YYhRiAB6APz2EAjIUIgAJhgCME4Yadp0uoGomDh4+JRg1J5SPlzhkdHx9emFUHCIwHRwAO6INGD0ysgwyAA0nAyIpWAA1voABh5e0hjz7gumxvPN-WmIqngLGVk5ef5rbYjz4pWS3qwcAEQ0j3LbsvaOLm5LNTJGmz6+nyumQoQi0ViCQUSTAKXSmWyuRBGiMxSwuAIFSqy1qzUaCQh2EyGm6GiSIDoe1UQhyYFSOBYiG61GwfSmag0NGQyEysAQ42arDodDKEym7RScFUiGsGDFjzakrQrigjwUsiAA)

```
function something<T>(initialState: T) { return { initialState } }
type Values = 'a' | 'b'

{
var initialState: Values = 'a';
//    ^?

const derivedValue = something(initialState)
//    ^?
// due to flow analysis, TS thinks `initialState` is `'a'`
// and pins `derivedValue` to `{ initialState: "a" }`
}

{
var initialState = 'a' as Values;
//    ^?

const derivedValue = something(initialState)
//    ^?
// here we could prevent that with a type assertion, 
// telling TS to stop being "too smart"
}
```

Comment: This works, but I can't say it makes sense why a normal type declaration would clog the flow.

Comment: TypeScript does flow analysis to a limited extend. With the normal variable declaration it knows "there could be a `Values` in here, but right now it's `a`". And when it reaches `something` it says "it's definitely `a` right now and even if it changes in the future, that function is now called with `a` - and treats the type as such.
If you do a `as Value` instead, you remove the "right now it is `a`" info because you tell the compiler to listen to you instead of thinking itself.